# Are ceramic materials suitable for making locking lugs for guns?

Tags: material-science

Since ceramics are resilient to shear loads, could one make locking lugs in a gun out of them or will tensile loads also be present leading to failure of such lugs? Also, could those tensile loads be decreased by decreasing the aspect ratio of the lugs?

Comment: And their resistance to shock loads? Aren’t ceramics brittle?

Comment: The basic assumption seems a bit odd, because shear loads are exactly equivalent to compressive and tensile loads at 45 degrees to the shear direction. Ceramics are usually described as strong in compression, but weak in both shear and tension.

Comment: Why not use steel the rest of the gun is made with ?

Answer (score 1):

ceramics exhibit very poor impact load resistance (low *toughness*) and are extremely notch-sensitive, making them unsuitable for use in gun actions. What you want instead is something that can absorb and sustain impact loads without damage, which argues in favor of steel which has been surface-hardened instead.